# Copying just text, not formulas, in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice, copy-paste, openoffice-calc

How do I copy and paste the text (not the formulas) from one Calc sheet to another in OpenOffice?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Select the cells you want to copy, and use Ctrl-C to copy them.
2. Select the cell where you want to copy the cells.
3. Open the **Edit->Paste Special** menu.
4. In the **Selection** section, ensure that the **Paste All** and **Formulas** options are **not** selected. Select all other options in that section.
5. Click OK, and the cells will be copied without the formulas.

Comment: In current libreoffice: copy like normal, right click -> paste only -> number.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't work for me but found that if I copied the result from a simple =EXACT etc formula, ie results were either TRUE or FALSE, and pasted it to Notepad, the results appeared as text and I could copy and paste them back to the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the accepted answer did not work, as it copied just the header of the column but no data.

What eventually worked out for me was:

1. Select cells to copy
2. Copy them (Either `Ctrl+C` or `Right click -> Copy`)
3. Right click where you want to paste and select `Paste Only -> Number`

Note that if you select `Paste Only -> Text` you will get a similar result but with just the data that was text (and not numbers). Hope this helps someone.